# Web Scraping in R when you have inputs

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a code for web scraping in R when you have to introduce inputs.
Exactly, I have a platform where I need to complete 2 fields and after that click submit and get the results.
But I don't know how to use my columns in R like inputs in platform.
I searched for an example but I did't find any.
Pls, if anyone can give me a simple e.g.

Thank you

EDIT:
I don't have a code yet. I was looking for an example where you can use input for complete a field on a site and after that to **scrape** the result.
[image]

In the photo are the fields on my URL. So, in R I have a dataframe with 2 columns. One for CNP/CUI and one for VIN/SASIU with 100 rows or more. And I want to use this columns like input and take the output for every row.

EDIT2:

The example provided by @Dominik S.Meier it worked for me when I had a list for inputs. For column inputs I will post another question.
But, till then I want to mention few thing that helped me, maybe it will hep somebody else.

1. You need to be sure that all the versions matches: R version, browser version, browser driver version, Java version. For me it didn't match chromedriver version, even if I downloaded the right version. The problem was that I had 3 chromeversion and I think it didn't choose the right. I fixed with: `rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),port = 4444L,chromever = "83.0.4103.39")`. More info here:[enter link description here](https://www.rpubs.com/widai/scraping_data_with_RSelenium)
2. Because one element didn't have `id` like in e.g. `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "trimite")`, I used `css selector`. You can find the `css selector` with right click -> copy -> copy selector (in the html code on the page).
3. If you don't get the results, maybe you don't use the right selector. I did that and the result was `list()`. Then I tried more `css selector` from the "above" in the html code. I don'y know if it is the right solution, but for me it worked.

Hope it will help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! We can help you better if you provide us with some more details, e.g. the code you tried so far.

Comment: Difficult to know what you want to do exactly and a repex would be nice. However, what you describe seems like a job for the `RSelenium` package, which allows you to interact with a website.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's clearer now. Thank you

Comment: You could use `set_values` from `rvest` or `RSelenium`. If you could share the url of the website I could offer more specific help

Comment: Unfortunately the url si private and you need user and pass. But here is other url with fields: https://pro.rarom.ro/istoric_vehicul/dosar_vehicul.aspx . The first field: an email adress, Second field: confirm email adress, Third field: Registration Number for a vehicle. Or if you know any other url. I just want an example where it used many values. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RSelenium` (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html#sending-text-to-elements) for more infos):

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox")) #specify browser type you want Selenium to open
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate("https://pro.rarom.ro/istoric_vehicul/dosar_vehicul.aspx") # navigates to webpage

# select first input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="inputEmail")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
option$sendKeysToElement(list("email@email.com"))

# select second input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="inputEmail2")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
option$sendKeysToElement(list("email@email.com"))


# select second input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="inputVIN")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
option$sendKeysToElement(list("123"))

#press key
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "trimite")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to run this code, but I have a error with browser `Could not open browser chrome`. The same issue with firefox. I tried to run selenium-server-standalone in cmd but after that what should to do? Also, I downloaded chromedriver, but it doesn't work. I need to mention that I am working on a laptop from my job and I don't have credentials to run apps like administrator. Anyway, do you have idea where is the pb with the code? Thank you

Comment: Yes getting the browser to work can be tricky. I suggest trying a few things, e.g., this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394733/using-rselenium-to-open-chrome-browser-getting-unable-to-create-new-service-c and make sure to check your chromedriver version matches e.g.: https://www.rpubs.com/widai/scraping_data_with_RSelenium

Comment: OMG, Thank you. I succeeded to run the code for an example on my url, even the query button. But how can I get the answer? I think the result it is a text, but how can I see this in R?

Comment: Nice! You can again use `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "trimite")` to find the element you are interested in and then if it is text use e.g., `elem_text <- webElem$getElementText()`

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried this also: `text <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#BdrCasIstoricForm > div.row > div > div > div.row > div > div > div.x_content > div > div > pre")$getElementAttribute("value")` and the result it's `list()`. The result is only a text on the page.

Comment: OMG, It worked. The pb was with the `css selector` on my case. Thank you very much for your help. You helped me a lot. Thank you. I will edit my post to tell all the details. Maybe it will help somebody else

Comment: One last question, if you tried this. I had a entire database with inputs (2 columns) with more rows and I can't put the values like a list (`option$sendKeysToElement(list(Data$CNP))`. So I tried to do a `for sentence`, but I got an error `Error:   Summary: UnknownError`. Do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: Sorry can't help you without more detailed information. But feel free to post another question.